# Java error: release version 14 not supported in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-14

I'm using IntelliJ to run a Java program, but I keep on getting this error "java: error: release version 14 not supported"

[image]

Comment: *FYI:* The version should be `14`, not `1.14`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot shows you are using JDK 11 as the project JDK and trying to target JDK 14 language level via the Maven configuration (I'd specify it as `14` instead of `1.14`).

To fix the problem change the project JDK to version 14.

Project Structure | Project SDK:

[image: JDK]

Comment: Shouldn't changing the pom.xml be sufficient, just asking if that's not already the expectation? (like IJ reads the version to use based on the maven configuration and fallback if not specified)

Answer (score 0):

I See from the external libraries that the project is set to run with java 11 JDK.

Update your project Settings to use java 14 and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Change language level from 14 to 7 works for me.

[image: change Language level]